# Can shapiro and normaltest be used interchangeably in python?

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I used to use `scipy.stats.shapiro` to test normality of data but seems like

```
 scipy.stats.normaltest
```

does the same.
Can they be used interchangeably without much difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138711/dagostino-pearson-vs-shapiro-wilk-for-normality) Shapiro seems to be generally better than D'Agostino-Pearson test used in `normaltest`.

> The ultimate reason why the Shapiro Wilk is popular has, I think, less
>   to do with Pubmed or NIST but rather with its excellent power in a
>   wide variety of situations of interest (which would in turn lead to
>   wider implementation and hence, popularity); it generally comes out
>   toward the top against a wide variety of non-normal distributions in
>   power comparisons with other possible choices. I wouldn't claim it's
>   the best possible omnibus test of normality, but it's a very solid
>   choice.